Why are these functions performing so differently?
I made two functions for adding vectors together so that I can add add together sine waves, one of them adds with the + operator and the other uses a lambda function to add them, which makes it easier for me to make functions for multiple operations. one of them takes 5 microseconds, the other takes around 17000.
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <numbers>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>

using i16 = int16_t;

constexpr float sample_rate = 44100;

std::vector<i16> sineWave(float frequency, float amplitude, float duration){
    int sampleCount = duration*sample_rate;
    std::vector<i16> samples(sampleCount);
    
    for(float i = 0;i<sampleCount;i++){
        samples[i] = static_cast<i16>(std::sin(2.0f*std::numbers::pi*frequency*(i/sample_rate))*amplitude);
    }
    
    return samples;
    
}

std::vector<i16> waveAdd(std::vector<i16>& wave1, std::vector<i16>& wave2){
    if(wave1.size() > wave2.size()){
        wave1.resize(wave2.size());
    }
    else if(wave2.size() > wave1.size()){
        wave2.resize(wave1.size());
    }
    
    std::vector<i16> final(wave1.size());
    for(size_t i = 0;i<wave1.size();i++){
        final[i] = wave1[i]+wave2[i];
    }
    return final;
}

std::vector<i16> waveOperation(std::vector<i16>& wave1, std::vector<i16>& wave2, std::function<i16(i16,i16)> operation){
    if(wave1.size() > wave2.size()){
        wave1.resize(wave2.size());
    }
    else if(wave2.size() > wave1.size()){
        wave2.resize(wave1.size());
    }
    
    std::vector<i16> final(wave1.size());
    for(size_t i = 0;i<wave1.size();i++){
        final[i] = operation(wave1[i],wave2[i]);
    }
    return final;
}

int main(){
    
    auto a = sineWave(10000,1000,20);
    
    auto b = sineWave(1000,2000,20);
    
    auto start1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto d = waveAdd(a,b);
    auto end1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
   
    auto start2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto c = waveOperation(a,b,[] (i16 a, i16 b) { return (a+b); } );
    auto end2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    
    auto duration1 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end1-start1);
    auto duration2 = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end2-start2);
    
    std::cout << "+ operator: " << duration1.count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "lambda: " << duration2.count() << std::endl; 
    
}

Is there a way that I can even this out, or would it be better to just make an equalize length helper function then copy and paste and change the operator?
I did run this in cpp.sh and not on my machine, but I don't think that makes much of a difference on the time it takes.

How do you compile the code? Did you compare optimized builds?

@jabaa I got the 5 and 17000 numbers on -O3, on -O0 it was around 80000 and 100000 with the + operator being faster

Please provide how you build the code and how you measure the time in your question?


is there a way that I can even this out, or would it be better to just make an equalize length helper function then copy and paste and change the operator?

First, understand that std::function carries a runtime performance cost.  Its type-erasure is not free!
Second, your lambda function moves compile-time information to runtime.  The compiler can optimize multiple adds, but will have a much harder time optimizing multiple calls to an arbitrary std::function::operator().
If you know what lambda you want at compile-time, pass the specific lambda you are using.
Either as a compile-time template parameter:
template<auto operation>
std::vector<i16> waveOperation(std::vector<i16>& wave1, std::vector<i16>& wave2){
    if(wave1.size() > wave2.size()){
        wave1.resize(wave2.size());
    }
    else if(wave2.size() > wave1.size()){
        wave2.resize(wave1.size());
    }
    
    std::vector<i16> final(wave1.size());
    for(size_t i = 0;i<wave1.size();i++){
        final[i] = operation(wave1[i],wave2[i]);
    }
    return final;
}

See the new results
Or as a deduced template type:
std::vector<i16> waveOperation(std::vector<i16>& wave1, auto& wave2, auto && operation ){
    if(wave1.size() > wave2.size()){
        wave1.resize(wave2.size());
    }
    else if(wave2.size() > wave1.size()){
        wave2.resize(wave1.size());
    }
    
    std::vector<i16> final(wave1.size());
    for(size_t i = 0;i<wave1.size();i++){
        final[i] = operation(wave1[i],wave2[i]);
    }
    return final;
}

See the new results
(Third, std::chrono::high_resolution_clock is never correct.  The clock for timing things is spelled std::chrono::steady_clock)

thanks, I haven't done much template programming and had no idea I could use them for functions

No need to pass a lambda as a template parameter: template<class O> std::vector<i16> waveOperation(std::vector<i16>& wave1, std::vector<i16>& wave2, O&& operation) and then you can pass the lambda as a plain parameter.
